# Не работает export js

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток :) возникла такая проблема: нужно написать скрипт, который читал бы значение переменной из другого скрипта.

есть скрипт в котором массив строк, его читает другой скрипт и получает значение в переменную

```
import { WORDS } from "/word.js";
let rightGuessString = WORDS[Math.floor(Math.random() * WORDS.length)]
```

с ним проблем нет, но они начинают когда я пытаюсь значение **rightGuessString** передать в другой html файл в скрипт, то есть:

```
...
let rightGuessString = WORDS[Math.floor(Math.random() * WORDS.length)]

console.log(rightGuessString)

const ans = rightGuessString;

export {ans};
...
```

```
...
<script type="module">
  import {ans} from "/script.js";

  let rightGuess = ans;

  elem.onclick = function check(){

  let row = document.getElementById("answer");
  let answer = row.value;                  
                    
  if(answer === rightGuess){
    toastr.success("Правильно!!!");
                        
    setTimeout(function(){
                                
      document.getElementById('Complete_btn').style.display='flex';
      document.getElementById('elem').style.display='none';
      },2000);

      return;
    }
    else{
      toastr.error("Попробуй ещё раз... :(");
      return;
    }
  }
</script>
```

То есть переменная **rightGuess** не получает значение **rightGuessString** и из-за этого не срабатывает дальнейший скрипт, если ввожу значение для **rightGuess** вручную, например:

```
<script type="module">

  elem.onclick = function check(){

  let row = document.getElementById("answer");
  let answer = row.value;                  
                    
  let rightGuess = "cat";

  if(answer === rightGuess){
    toastr.success("Правильно!!!");
                        
    setTimeout(function(){
                                
      document.getElementById('Complete_btn').style.display='flex';
      document.getElementById('elem').style.display='none';
      },2000);

      return;
    }
    else{
      toastr.error("Попробуй ещё раз... :(");
      return;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Всё прекрасно работает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы из одного скрипта .js файла можно было передать значение в скрипт html

Comment: У меня не получается повторить проблему, я добавил `console.log(rightGuess)` и он у меня вывел в точности то же самое, что и в вашем `console.log(rightGuessString)`

Comment: Писать код  в тэге HTML - плохая практика. Подключите второй js-файл.